# Question about rotating a slider

Tags: iphone

I am working on an application which needs to rotate the slider at one end. However, by using CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(), I can only rotate the slider at the centre.

What should I do in order to rotate the slider at the end point? If possible, please give a short paragraph of sample code. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I rotate a `UIImageView` by setting the `anchorPoint` property for the view's layer. e.g.

```
myView.layer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.5, 1.0);
```

and then applying a `CATransform3DRotate` as the layer's `transform` property

```
CATransform3D rotationTransform = CATransform3DIdentity;
rotationTransform = CATransform3DRotate(rotationTransform, positionInRadians, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
myView.layer.transform = rotationTransform;
```

I found this from Apple's [metronome](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/Metronome/index.html) example, so it's worth checking that out. Hope that helps

Comment: Thank you very much. I have succeeded in transforming the slider.

Answer (score 1):

I second cidered's answer. To do what you want using CGAffineTransforms, you have to compose transformations until you get the effect you're looking for:

```
CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(1.0);
transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(transform, slider.frame.size.width / 2, 0.0);
slider.transform = transform;
```