# UIImage iPhone Rotate 37.8 degrees

Tags: iphone, uiimage, rotation

After I load an image from the device, I need to rotate it 37.8 degrees then display it on a View.

Is there an function in Objective-C that can do the image rotation?

Ian

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To rotate the view:

```
imageView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(37.8°);
```

To rotate the image,

1. Calculate the width and height will be occupied by the image after rotation.
2. Create a `CGContext` by `UIGraphicsBeginImageContext`.
3. `CGContextRotateCTM(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 37.8°);`
4. `[yourImage drawAtPoint:...];`
5. `UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();` and use this image instead.
6. Release the context.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, see my answer to this question: [Question about rotating a slider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1999309/question-about-rotating-a-slider/1999389#1999389)

To convert degrees to radians (for the positionInRadians arg) use this function:

```
CGFloat DegreesToRadians(CGFloat degrees) {return degrees * M_PI / 180;};
```

Comment: I need to rotate just the image though, not the view. Is that possible?

Comment: Can't you just load the image into a UIImageView and add it as a subview? Otherwise I see KennyTM has answered how to take a UIImage and rotate to get another UIImage.

Answer (score 1):

To rotate the image, try this:

```
-(IBAction)rotateImageClick:(id)sender{

    UIImage *image2=[[UIImage alloc]init];
    image2 = [self imageRotatedByDegrees:self.roateImageView.image deg:(90)]; //Angle by 90 degree
    self.roateImageView.image = image2;
    imgData= UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image2,0.9f);

}
```

This method allows you to rotate an image an arbitrary amount:

```
- (UIImage *)imageRotatedByDegrees:(UIImage*)oldImage deg:(CGFloat)degrees{

    // calculate the size of the rotated view's containing box for our drawing space
    UIView *rotatedViewBox = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,oldImage.size.width, oldImage.size.height)];

    CGAffineTransform t = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(degrees * M_PI / 180);
    rotatedViewBox.transform = t;

    CGSize rotatedSize = rotatedViewBox.frame.size;
    // Create the bitmap context
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rotatedSize);
    CGContextRef bitmap = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    // Move the origin to the middle of the image so we will rotate and scale around the center.
    CGContextTranslateCTM(bitmap, rotatedSize.width/2, rotatedSize.height/2);

    //   // Rotate the image context
    CGContextRotateCTM(bitmap, (degrees * M_PI / 180));

    // Now, draw the rotated/scaled image into the context
    CGContextScaleCTM(bitmap, 1.0, -1.0);
    CGContextDrawImage(bitmap, CGRectMake(-oldImage.size.width / 2, -oldImage.size.height / 2, oldImage.size.width, oldImage.size.height), [oldImage CGImage]);

    UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return newImage;

}
```

See [this link](http://adrianmobileapplication.blogspot.com/2015/03/rotate-original-image-by-clicking.html) for more information.